# Showing / Hiding Div With jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using `toggle()` but it's not working. My script is in the footer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("product-suggestion-form-container").click(function(){
      $("form-div-top").toggle();
   });
});
```

or I've also tried `addClass()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("product-suggestion-form-container").click(function(){
      $("form-div-top").addClass("active");  
         // $("form-div-top").toggle();
   });
});
```

Basically I'm just trying to toggle between showing and hiding the form divs.

When `product-suggestion-form-container` is clicked on, `form-div-top` should show.

When `contact-us-form-container` is clicked on, `form-div-bottom` should show.

Then they should hide when those divs are clicked on again.

Shouldn't clicking on `product-suggestion-form-container` cause `form-div-top` to become active and therefore to `display: flex`? Not sure why nothing's happening.

I was just getting the jQuery from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle), but ideally I'd like to add a smooth transition and whatever other best practices you might suggest for doing this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("product-suggestion-form-container").click(function(){
      $("form-div-top").addClass("active");  
         // $("form-div-top").toggle();
   });
});
```

```css
.form-div-outer {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.form-div-top,
.form-div-bottom {
  background-color: #f8f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

/*initial display*/

.form-div-inner-top {
  display: none;
}

.form-div-inner-bottom {
  display: none;
}

.form-div-inner-top:active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-div-inner-bottom:active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-input {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-div-outer">
   <div class="product-suggestion-form-container">
      <span class="form-title">Product Suggestion Form</span>
         <span class="dropdown-arrow"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
         </span>
   </div>
   <div class="form-div-top">
      <form class="form-div-inner-top">
         <span class="input-group input-group-name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-input" required></input>
         </span>
         <span class="input-group input-group-email-address">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-input" required></input>
         </span>
         <span class="input-group description-of-product-desired">
            <input type="textarea" placeholder="Description of product desired" class="form-input" required></input>
         </span>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-div-outer">
  <div class="contact-us-form-container">
    <span class="form-title">Contact Us Form</span>
    <span class="dropdown-arrow"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-div-bottom">
    <form class="form-div-inner-bottom">
      <span class="input-group input-group-name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-input" required></input>
      </span>
      <span class="input-group input-group-email-address">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-input" required></input>
      </span>
      <span class="input-group input-group-contact-reason">
      <div class="contact-reason-container">
        <ul class="radiolist">
          <li>
            <input class="radio" type="radio"><label>Order question</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio"><label>Website feedback</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio"><label>Trouble finding product</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     </span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selectors are missing  dot prefix and thus looking for tags like `<product-suggestion-form-container></product-suggestion-form-container>` that don't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have forgot `.`s in your code to access the data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".product-suggestion-form-container").click(function(){
  $(".form-div-top").toggle();
 });
});
```

Comment: This is just a  typo issue and should be voted to close as it has no long term use for future readers

Comment: Whatever you feel best :)

Comment: I mean - if you delete your answer, I can delete the post, correct? Either way - thanks for the help. It might help a future user who has the same typo.

Comment: I guess Let's keep the question as well as the answer mate. Let's help other's :)

Comment: This doesn't help others . It's simply a typo and there is a close reason for typos

Comment: @charlietfl: May be you are right but with respect dear Charlietfl, let's keep it there to support newbies. Typo can sometimes be so frustrating and hours go by without figuring what was the issue.. Let's keep it SIr. :) Thanks

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather, I put +1 to your solution, as I understand your desire to help the author of the question :)

Comment: That's absurd. Tell me what the odds are that someone searches for hide/show and has the exact same selector prefix issue? Those odds are astronomical. The typo close reason is there for a very good reason...to remove useless issues for future users

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov : Thank you mate. God Bless you. You know how much good it feels to help others :)